# Alternative for object.should_not_receive(:message) in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Old code to check receive in rspec

```
object.should_receive(:message)
```

As per the new rspec syntex,we can write this code to check should_recieve

```
allow(object).to receive(:message)
```

But how do I check for something like this

```
allow(object).to_not receive(:message)
```

earlier we used to check this way

```
object.should_not_receive(:message)  # I need a new syntax with latest rspec.
```

I am not able to find any doc

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
expect(object).not_to receive(:message)
```